# HP EliteBook 810 G1 - Touchscreen partially not working

Tags: windows-10, touchscreen

I have problems with some of our HP EliteBook 810 G1 Revolve.
On some of them the touchscreen isn't working at the top part of the screen.

[image: Image showing working area of the touchscreen]

In the picture above the area is hilighted that do work. And in this area touch works withour problems.

Windows lists the screen as a Standard PnP-Screen.
[image: PNPScreen]

I've updated BIOS and all the drivers to the latest available and windows is also up to date.

Any hints on what to try next is greatly appreciated!

---

SystemInfo

[image: System Info]
Above is from System Info screen and the line "Penna och pekskärm" shows support for pen and touch input.

[image: Tablet PC settings]
I've tried to run the Configure setup from Tablet PC settings page.
And also tried to calibrate the screen but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Contacting HP might just be your best bet. We can't investigate and repair a hardware issue if it exists. You could potentially have a bad batch on your hands, or there's some other information that HP could provide.

Comment: I'm afraid that is the way forward to but hoping someone have had the same problems and have a fix. :)

Comment: uninstall the display and GPU driver, reboot and reinstall them. look if this helps